# What is a "minute thread"?

Tags: meaning, homographs

> Each caterpillar unravels a single strand of delicate raw silk from its salivary glands and wraps the **minute thread** thousands of times around its body in a figure of eight pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context the word "***minute***" means very, very small. In this sentence, it is talking about how small/thin the strands of silk are. Synonyms of "minute" are "*miniscule*" or "*tiny*".

This can be confusing, because the word "minute" has a variety of other meanings in English, including as a unit of time (*"there are 60 minutes in an hour"*), as units in geographical coordinates/bearings (*"the ship plotted a course towards 2 degrees, 10 minutes east"*) and as a form of written records of proceedings during meetings/conferences/etc (*"the secretary kept detailed minutes of each of the board's meetings"*).

However, while they are spelled the same, these latter two senses of the word are pronounced differently in spoken English. When referring to something tiny as "*minute*", the word is pronounced like "*my-noot*" whereas the other two senses are both pronounced more like "*min-nett*".